# How to remap "vi-search-again" in .inputrc?

Tags: bash, vi, readline, inputrc

I use Colemak + Bash Vi mode, and have remapped `h` `j` `k` `l` to `h` `n` `e` `i` in `.inputrc`.

The original `N` `n` keys for repeating search seem to be bound to the same command:

```bash
$ # Run in command mode
$ bind -p | grep vi-search-again
"N": vi-search-again
"n": vi-search-again
```

So I tried remapping this command to `K` `k`:

```bash
set keymap vi-command
    "n": history-search-forward
    "N": ""
    "K": vi-search-again                                                     
    "k": vi-search-again
```

After restarting Bash, `vi-search-again` has been remapped:

```
$ # Run in command mode
$ bind -p | grep vi-search-again
"K": vi-search-again
"k": vi-search-again
```

But pressing `K` `k` during a "/" search produces no response.  What is the correct way to remap this command?